# Gravity Between a Pair of Triangles

Tags: java, game-physics, physics-engine, jbullet

Given two triangles in 3D, defined by points `[t1.v1, t1.v2, t1.v3]` and `[t2.v1, t2.v2, t2.v3]`, where v*X* are points with variables `(x, y, z)`.

How can I calculate the force of gravity between them?

Formula for point masses:

```
force = constant*mass1*mass2/(distance^2);
```

For my application, the triangles will be close together, and approximating via point masses would not have the required precision.

I understand that this could be solved with a quadruple integral, but I don't have much mathematical know-how towards creating or solving such a complicated equation.

**Edit:**

My similar (related) question on math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082860/general-solution-for-the-gravity-between-two-3d-triangles/

Comment: Have you already seen http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1082860/general-solution-for-the-gravity-between-two-3d-triangles?

Comment: Um... yes.  I posted it. :)

Comment: Ah, well, it'd be good to link to it, since it gives a good perspective on this problem. What sort of exactness are you needing? game physics isn't known for being precise.